# Don’t show self-starred questions in the counter

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

A lot of the time, when a new user asks their first question, they star it (I did this myself). This leads to many questions that nobody actually was particularly interested saying that they were starred by someone.

**Can the stars of the OPs be ignored in the counter?** It’s very useless information, and slightly misleading.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the benefits this would do?

Comment: Stars don't necessarily imply that a question is good, they're just a bookmarking tool. FWIW, on SO I often star bad questions temporarily, so I can easily find them when they're eligible for deletion.

Comment: If they're no indication of anything then the numbers shouldn't be shown.

Comment: @curiousdannii They're indicative of interest, but not all interest is good.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see what benefit would be earned to remove the OP's own starring from the count.

> It’s very useless information, and slightly misleading.

It's only one count, and I don't believe that's misleading anyways.
People star questions for various reasons, to easily come back later on these. Stars are no matter of indicating quality, popularity or on-topicness of questions.

So I don't think it's worth to spend any effort on this.